# running bash executables from Windows application

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a rather complicated setup running on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) which I can't really replicate properly on native Windows. I develop Ruby applications and would love to be able to call my Ruby, Rspec etc. from Aptana, which is my Windows-based IDE. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: What about running a VM?

Comment: A Linux VM you mean? That would widen the gap even more wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can run Linux binaries from Windows by invoking them with `wsl.exe` like so:

```
wsl ./your_script.sh
```

You can read more about this in the [WSL interoperability with Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop) docs.

If you would like to call such commands from within your IDE, you need to setup some custom scripts or builders. For Aptana, which is based on Eclipse you can add so-called external builders. You can find out more about them in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670891/eclipse-c-c-project-on-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows).